# Listing all user-defined definitions used in a function call

Tags: programming, evaluation, code-request

Is it possible to obtain all user defined definitions (and attributes) that are used in the evaluation of certain command (or alternatively just their symbols which I could imagine being easier when symbols carry both used and unused definitions/attributes). I want to use this in order to quickly be able to share a minimal amount of code required to make a certain command run correctly.

Minimal example:

```
f[x_] := 3;
traceUserDefinedDefinitions[f[4]];
```

would return `{"f[x_]:=3"}` (or some equivalent format).

Comment: How would you share this code?

Comment: @Carl, I would like to share a notebook. Some editing might of course be required afterwards to make the code shareable but I would like to automatically generate a notebook that at least requires all the code required to run the command of interest.

Comment: @Syed. The example was perhaps too simple. I meant of course that `f` might contain calls to many other user defined functions. However, it seems that `FullDefinition` might simply give what I need.

Comment: I removed my comment that proposed `Information[f]` after realizing that you had a more complicated task at hand.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the framework that Wolfram cloud uses to transfer content:

```
CreateNotebookDefinition[f_]:=With[{def=Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[f]},
    CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[Defer[Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[f] = def], "Input"]]
]
```

Using `CreateNotebookDefinition` will create a notebook with an input cell that will recreate the desired definitions.

Answer (score 5):

A primitive start would be to simply use `Trace`, and then look for all user-defined symbols that appear.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a = 7;
f[x_] := 3 x^2;
g[x_, y_] := f[2 x];
h[x_] := Sqrt[f[x] - g[x, 5 x] - a];
i[x_, y_] := Exp[-x + y];

SetAttributes[traceUserDefinedDefinitions, HoldFirst];
traceUserDefinedDefinitions[expr_] := 
 DeleteDuplicates@
  Cases[Trace[expr, TraceOriginal -> True], 
   Alternatives @@ (ToExpression[Names["Global`*"], InputForm, 
      HoldForm]), All]

traceUserDefinedDefinitions[h[4]]
(* {h, f, g, a} *)
```

You may then use [@Carl Woll's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/289100/75628) (or some other way to obtain full definitions of symbols) to export definitions to a new notebook:

```
CreateNotebookDefinition[traceUserDefinedDefinitions[h[4]]]
```

Comment: Note that ``Language`ExtendedFullDefinition`` already finds dependent symbols (this is what the Full means), so it is not necessary to use your `traceUserDefinedDefinitions` function

Comment: @CarlWoll, imagine `a = 1; g[x_] := x;`. One cannot use only your method to determine that running `g[a]` requires the definition of `a`, right? Namely, ```Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[g]``` will not include `a`.

Comment: If the intention (unclear) is to have definitions so that evaluating an expression (that contains multiple symbols) will work, then you are correct. Still., it would be simpler to just find all symbols in the expression, and then use ``Language`ExtendedFullDefinition`` on them instead of using Trace.